# Printing asterisks from file data

Tags: c, loops, file-io

I am new to programming in C and I have the following task to complete:

Write a program that reads from a file with three numbers. First two numbers represent the height and width of a rectangle generated using asterisks (*). The third number represents a recurring gap among the `(*)` on each row of the rectangle.

Example file layout
5
8
3

Console output

```
** ** **
** ** **
** ** **
** ** **
** ** **
```

... I am OK when it comes to reading the file, I have just hit a road block when it comes to replacing the numbers with asterisks and adding a space. I understand that I should be looking at learning loops probably a `for` for this particular task.

Please could someone give me some good websites, reading material or code hints where I can try and learn about loops, there are so many websites out there I just wondered where the best place for a begginer in C such as myself should go to learn quickly and efficiently.

Any recommendations would be great :)

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this is strictly off-topic as defined by site policy. You should try googling for some c tutorials on loops, modulo and `printf`. It's all basics. However it is asked nicely, better than many on topic questions IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two nested [`for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) loops, the outer for lines and the inner for columns. In the inner, add a check that for every N (where N is the third number) you print a space instead of an asterisk.

Comment: Dear, Joachim, whom I really respect greatly. Is that an answer? It is a hint for the OP. This is unanswerable, because there is no question. Just asking for materials. Or I am wrong and should review my stance. I am just not sure if there is any use in posting answers to questions going strictly against the current policy.

Comment: Cheers Joachim, much appreciated!